# What is the maximum number of free variables for a given matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

For example what is the maximum number of free variables for a 5x7 augmented matrix.

Will there always be at least one pivot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A matrix will have at least one pivot in its row-reduced form if (and only if) it is non-zero. So, a $5 \times 7$ matrix with $7$ free variables it possible, but the only such matrix is the zero matrix.

Comment: if it is not a zero matrix, then will the maximum number of free variables = 6 ?

Comment: @rsonx That's correct